# Sorting according to Second Element of Tuples in Lists in a Dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, tuples, dictionary-comprehension

Now I have the following dictionary containing lists, with tuples being elements of each list:

```
dict1 = {'it': [('was', 4)], 'was': [('the', 4)], 'the': [('best', 1), ('worst', 1), ('age', 2)], 'best': [('of', 1)], 'of': [('times', 2), ('wisdom', 1), ('foolishness', 1)], 'times': [('it', 2)], 'worst': [('of', 1)], 'age': [('of', 2)], 'wisdom': [('it', 1)]}
```

I need to sort the dictionary according to the frequencies of each value (Second element of each tuple) using **dictionary comprehension**.
The expected output is:

```
{'it': ['was'], 'was': ['the'], 'the': ['age', 'best', 'worst'], 'best': ['of'], 'of': ['times', 'wisdom', 'foolishness'], 'times': ['it'], 'worst': ['of'], 'age': ['of'], 'wisdom': ['it']}
```

I tried with the following code:

```
dict2 = {k:sorted([pair[0] for pair in v],key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True) for k,v in dict1.items()}
```

but the output turns out to be:

```
{'it': ['was'], 'was': ['the'], 'the': ['worst', 'age', 'best'], 'best': ['of'], 'of': ['foolishness', 'times', 'wisdom'], 'times': ['it'], 'worst': ['of'], 'age': ['of'], 'wisdom': ['it']}
```

The orders of values of keys 'the' and 'of' are mixed up. How should I correct my code?

Comment: No that isn't OP's issue. They do seem to want the elements reversed, what's wrong is the list-comp prior to sorting @python_learner

Comment: removing `reverse=True` makes sense for the 'of' key but not 'the' key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're quite close, but you seem to be filtering out the tuples, and then using a key function, which is redundant. Also, you are keeping only the words prior to sorting, so really what you're doing there is sorting based on the *second character* of those words, since now your iterable in each call to the *key* function is the actual string. This might make it clearer:

```
test = [('1z', 2), ('2a', 1), ('3d', 1)]
sorted([pair[0] for pair in test], key=lambda x: x[1])
# ['2a', '3d', '1z']
```

You could just sort the list of tuples and order based on the second items times `-1`:

```
{k: [i[0] for i in sorted(v, key=lambda x: -x[1])] for k,v in d.items()}
{'it': ['was'],
 'was': ['the'],
 'the': ['age', 'best', 'worst'],
 'best': ['of'],
 'of': ['times', 'wisdom', 'foolishness'],
 'times': ['it'],
 'worst': ['of'],
 'age': ['of'],
 'wisdom': ['it']}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what times -1 actually mean? Thanks.

Comment: It mimics the behaviour of `reversed=True` @cwyjm

Comment: It is the same as `sorted(v, key=lambda x: x[1], reversed=True)` @cwyjm

Comment: Got it! This would be a more convenient way than including `reverse`. Thank you so much! :)